# HTML - hovering doesn't work in Safari after embeded video is started. Works in FIrefox

Tags: html, css, video, safari

I am reworking my website and hit two issues that I would like help with if possible.

The link to the test site is http://elovideo.com/test/index.html

1)  I am adding embeded video with a poster so that it doesn't download when the page loads.  When I view the page in Firefox and click on the movie, the hover still works on my other hyperlinks.  My links light up, an underline appears or the hand is visible all indicating that those items can be selected.

However in Safari, once the video is selected my hover doesn't work.  I am still able to click on the links, but for someone new to my site they wouldn't realize that some of the text is a hyperlink.  The hover works fine prior to selecting the video for view/loading.

2)  A dotted box appears around my video viewer when the movie is played in Firefox.  I would like to be able to stop that from occurring.  It doesn't happen in Safari.

I am quite certain the fault lies in user error as I am not highly skilled in writing code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I am doing something wrong, please let me know.

Thanks!
Erica

Style sheet CSS Code BELOW - HTML can be viewed on website source listed above.

```
html, body , ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
img {

    border: 0;
}
a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.more {
    text-align: right;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, form {
    font: 14px tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #7a895d; repeat-x;

}

body {

    background: #7a895d url(images/headerback.jpg) repeat-x;



    text-align: left;
}

#bodyinner {
    background: url(images/white.jpg) repeat-y;



    width: 960px;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px 20px 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}



#wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #7a895d ;

}


#header {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;


}
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#header h1 img {
    display: block;

}

#bnav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 200px;



}
#bnav img {
    float: left;
}



#nav {
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: 200px;



}
#nav img {
    float: left;
}

#headline {
    padding: 210px 0px 0px 10px;


}

#photo {
    float: left;
    width: 624px;
}
#photo div {
    border: 1px solid #a5b87c;
    padding: 2px;
}
#photo img {
    display: block;
}

#search-news {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;



}
#search-news div {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
#search-news #q {
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #859D31;
    margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
#search-news .downcast {
    background: #E6E7E7;
    border-top: 1px solid #CFD0D0;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin: 0.2em 0 0.4em 1em;
}
#search-news h3 {
    background: url(images/bullet_letter.gif) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1em 0 0.4em 1em;


}
#search-news p {
    padding-left: 15px;

    padding-right: 2px;
    margin: 1em 0 0.4em 1em;
background: #7a895d repeat-x;
}
a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5C5C5C;

}



#body-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 408px;

}
#body-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 450px;

}

#body-full {
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;


}



#body-left ul.plussbullets {
    margin-top: 245px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;


}
#body-left ul.plussbullets li {
    background: top left url(images/bullet_plus.gif) repeat-x;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#body h2, #body p {
    margin: 0.3em 0;

}

#body-right p {
    margin-right: 2em;

}

#body a.green {
    color: #9AAB68;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#gallery img {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 5px 5px;

}

#footer {
    color: #FFFFFF;

    background: #42453D url(images/footer_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your page does not seem to work in Firefox 5...

Comment: That's confusing as I am using Firefox 5 to view it.    Hmmm

Comment: I found that in Safari if I click anywhere else on the page that isn't in the video box or another hyperlink, that my hover capabilities come back.  I'm thinking that I must have to shift focus after the video is clicked.  Does this sound feasible?

Comment: just tested again in Firefox.  I saw code on the page earlier, but it seems to work fine now, weird. I also notice that I don't see the red box around the video in Firefox. Also, the 2nd and 4th items in the sidebar are missing `<a>` tags, so they aren't links in Firefox nor in Safari.  Other than that, the link hover works fine for both browsers for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what is being referenced in your first question. I don't see a hover working in either browser type.

In regards to removing the dotted outline, you want to use the following CSS for your object:

outline: none;